# How do I work with setTransient and getTransient in Node.js for Hyperledger 1.4.4 (examples)?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

At this point I was unable to find clear examples on how to use getTransient in Node.js. Maybe you can help me just with the right link.

Assume I have a client application in Node.js that submits something like:

```js
const privatePayload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({"Args":args})).toString('base64');
const result = await contract.createTransaction(func).setTransient({"privatePayload" : privatePayload}).submit();
```

In my Node.js chaincode I have something like this:

```js
var MAP = ctx.stub.getTransient();
...
```

What I see, is that data comes in form of

```
{ privatePayload:
   { key: 'privatePayload'
     value: 
       ByteBuffer {
buffer: <Buffer 0a c1 .... >,
offset: ...,
...
}
```

I access this buffer, decode it and see, that it contains not only my payload as a string, but also name of OrgMSP, CERTIFICATE, channel information etc all in one block. My payload is at the end.

Is there a ready to use API to just access my payload? 
What is the actual format of this buffer?

Comment: I am facing an issue i tried the exact same code but the issue is  when i try 
   let transientData = await ctx.stub.getTransient(); from chaincode I am getting am empty response. 

My nodeJS client code is 

        const privatePayload =   Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(args))
        const result = await contract.createTransaction(functionName).setTransient({"privatePayload" : privatePayload}).submit();

Is there anything more i need to add

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `chaincodeStub.getTransient().get('key').toString('utf8')`

Answer (score 1):

And you don't have to use "await" with getTransient() since the function already returns a map of values. Just something like that would work:

```
var MAP = ctx.stub.getTransient();
```